# python thread terminate or kill in the best way

Tags: python, python-multithreading

The thing is I want to kill all the thread that are currently running.For example I have a single button whose calling the for loop. and suddenly I want to stop it.

here are my codes:

```
class WorkerThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,t,*args):
        super(WorkerThread,self).__init__(target=t,args=(args[0],args[3]))
        self.start()
        self.join()
```

my implementation:

```
def running(fileopen,methodRun):
    #....long task of code are here...


for file in fileTarget:
        threads.append(WorkerThread(running,file,count,len(fileTarget),"FindHeader"))
```

Comment: set a boolean flag that locks the thread execution block, soon or later you can change the state of the flag, letting the thread to finish its run method cleanly....

Comment: hi sir, thank you for your suggestion could you show some codes to handle that? 2 to 4 lines of code will do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to kill a Thread in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python)

Answer (score 5):

**Never try to abruptly terminate a thread.** Instead setup a flag/signal in your `WorkerThread` class, and then when you want it to stop just set the flag and make the thread finish by itself.

Also you have misunderstandings on how to subclass `threading.Thread`. If you decide to run a function as thread, it should be:

```
thread = threading.Thread(target=my_func, args=(arg1, arg2...))
thread.start()
```

Well, in your case this won't fit for your needs since you want the thread to stop when requested. So now let's subclass `threading.Thread`, basically **`__init__` is like a constructor** in python, every time when an instance is created it'll get executed. And you immediately `start()` the thread and then block it with `join()`, what it does is in your for loop `threads.append(WorkerThread(running,file,count,len(fileTarget),"FindHeader"))` will block till the end of `running` finished with `file` and then goes on to work with another `file`, no actual thread is being used.

You should move your `running(fileopen,methodRun)` into **[`run()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.run)**:

```
class WorkerThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,*args):
        super(WorkerThread,self).__init__()
        self.arg_0 = arg[0]
        self.arg_1 = arg[1]
        ...
        self.stop = False

    def run(self):
        # now self.arg_0 is fileopen, and self.arg_1 is methodRun
        # move your running function here
        #....long task of code are here...

        Try to do self.stop check every small interval, e.g.

        ...

        if self.stop:
            return

        ...



for file in fileTarget:
    new_thread = WorkerThread(file, count, len(fileTarget), "FindHeader"))
    new_thread.start()

    threads.append(new_thread)

# Stop these threads
for thread in threads:
    thread.stop = True
```